# Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list [Javascript Syntax Error]

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax

I've got this error `Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list` when trying to

```
var email = 'admin@admin.com';
$('<div class="shareBtnBlockOlly"><a class="tweet" href="javascript:Share.twitter('+email+')" target="_blank">Twitter</a></div>').insertAfter('.objectCollectModalShareContent h4');
```

Where is my problem? Can't solve this today, i guess im to sleepy or just too broken before weekends..

Comment: Use `href="javascript:Share.twitter(\"' + email + '\")"`

Comment: I'd suggest to add the events in JavaScript, what you are doing concatenating JS inside strings is a recipe for disaster...

Comment: Now it throws me `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input`

Comment: @ReyCreed Kindly debug your code. Check for opening and closing, nesting quotes, etc.

Comment: This is caused by your `var email` it uses single quotes but `$('<div class="shareBtnBlockOlly">` also uses single quotes

Answer (score 1):

```
$('<div class="shareBtnBlockOlly"><a class="tweet" href="javascript:Share.twitter(\'' + email + '\')" target="_blank">Twitter</a></div>').insertAfter('.objectCollectModalShareContent h4');
```

Because you started with double quotes, add parameters with single quotes.